# Scripting a file copy from Mac to Windows (IIS) machine

Tags: macos, bash, iis, command-line

I'm getting permission denied attempting to copy a file at the command-line from my Mac to a remote Windows IIS server.  I have access to the IIS server and have confirmed that I have write permissions to the folder.  I can remote desktop to the server and navigate and work in the directories i want. I can copy the file successfully using Finder. From the Terminal command-line  I'm able to mount a volume, navigate, ls and cat the file in the directory i'm trying to cp to.

```
$cp -f ham.html /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html
cp: /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html: Permission denied

$ ls -l ham.html
-rw-r--r--  1 kellykx  LEGAL\Domain Users  18218 Jul 29 22:58 ham.html

$ ls -ld 
drwxr-xr-x  31 kellykx  LEGAL\Domain Users  1054 Jul 29 23:02 .

$ ls -l /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html
-rwx------+ 1 kellykx  LEGAL\Domain Users  18218 Jul 29 15:23 /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html

$ ls -ld /Volumes/external-api
drwx------+ 1 johnsob2  LEGAL\Domain Users  16384 Jul 29 17:53 /Volumes/external-api
```

I'm worried there's some IIS voodoo i'm missing.  Or worse, something obviously trivial.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Can you post the output to the following? `ls -l ham.html`, `ls -ld`, `ls -l /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html`, `ls -ld /Volumes/external-api`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you logged in as `kellykx`? There appear to be some `ACLs` set on the `/Volumes/external-api/eggs.html` file and `/Volumes/external-api` directory. Can you run the following to show what those `ACLs` are? `ls -le /Volumes/external-api/eggs.html` and `ls -lde /Volumes/external-api`. The permissions as they stand appear to show that you would expect to get the permission denied error because you are not the owner of the directory `/Volumes/external-api/` and `group` and `world` have no read and execute access. Are you able to change the owner to yourself, or make the group permissions `r-x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The permissions of the Windows share were more restrictive than the file system permissions and took precedence, causing the permission denied message. The Windows share permission was r while the underlying directory and files were rw, as shown.

To resolve: 
I used remote desktop to login to the Windows server. 
Navigated file manager to the parent dir of external-api,
Right clicked and followed properties->Sharing->Advanced Sharing->Permissions
Selected my name from the list box -- already set up when the share was created
Checked Full Control, Change and Read checkboxes.

Open question:
How do you inspect permissions of mounted SMB share from the OSX command line? The equiv of ls -l.